# Display image from gallery using fresco library

Tags: android, android-studio, fresco

I'm using fresco library in my android project and I'm trying to set the image from gallery.

```
photoHolder = (SimpleDraweeView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.selectPhoto);

photoHolder.setImageURI(uri);
```

and this is the value of uri: `content://media/external/images/media/987`

I get that uri from onActivityResult when I select a photo from the gallery like:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       ..
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    ...
}
```

Drawee:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
```

I don't get any errors but the image is not being displayed.

I tried all that I could find online, but without complaining I don't know what could be wrong with it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your layout? Maybe there can be some problem there.

Comment: @thetonrifles that's my drawee

Comment: http://frescolib.org/docs/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting. There are instructions there on how to set up debug logs.

Comment: ok, but where this SimpleDraweeView is located into? I mean... if you don't have any error when using `setImageURI`, it's possible that image is rendered properly but maybe the `SimpleDraweeView` is not visible due to some problem in layout around it.

Comment: @thetonrifles I changed to glide and everything is working fine. The position was not the problem

Comment: @tyronen the file path shouldn t be the problem since it's working with glide

Comment: Have exactly the same problem, did you find any solution ?

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions declared in manifest ? That was the reason why it didn't work for me
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I am too facing same problem, while setting image from gallery. The image is set properly while using native Imageview.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue with the minor difference of loading images from the app private storage folder.

the .jpg was stored on the path like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xyz.app.packagename/files/Pictures/24.08.2017 02:36:30.jpg
```

You can then proceed by checking if your path is a legit File by doing:

```
File imageFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xyz.app.packagename/files/Pictures/24.08.2017 02:36:30.jpg");
boolean isValidFile = imageFile.isFile();
if (isValidFile){
    photoHolder.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
}
```

Hope this helps someone.